# want requirements for generating browser key for google maps places

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to develop an android application using google places. I want to show my search places as autocomplete in a textview. My questions are:

1. What is the requirement for generating a browser key?
2. What would I have to include in the server folder?

   enter code here

public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

```
private ArrayList<String> resultList;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

private static final String API_KEY = " AIzaSyCT6NeHAUlC9j6qYi63TxkCXgA56FQU1hc";
public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return resultList.get(index);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                filterResults.values = resultList;
                filterResults.count = resultList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }};
    return filter;
}

protected ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?sensor=true&key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:uk");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you want to process for generating browse key?

Comment: yeah !! https://code.google.com/apis/console after click on browser key. what i have to provide(i.e which server and what should be in that server )

Comment: just nothing you have to just give domain name..and create your browser key.

Comment: i followed that only but its not working.. any certification needed for that domain. or any files we have to keep in server domain

Comment: no...for that no other certification given... But if you are using google places then create android key for that..

Comment: i have that key and this is code snippet MainActivity.java

Comment: So..have you used android key in your java file?

Comment: i edit my query with code i am having andoid key also.. see that (is it in that  format or not? thank you

Comment: ok..but after implement have you got any error?

Comment: nothing some times in log cat access denied (null response)